# JUnit import cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I'm currently trying to create JUnit tests for my Java project (eclipse). However, a weird error keeps showing whenever I add a new JUnit Test Case to my project:
https://ibb.co/ekon9J
When I try to use the Quick Fix function of the Eclipse, it adds the JUnit 5 to the build path again, although it's already there. All seems to be set up correctly, but it's still not working. I tried cleaning/closing the project as someone suggested in a similar thread. Unfortunately, nothing helped me. Does anyone have an idea on what's going on here?

[EDIT]: Here's the print screen of the Java Build Path libraries tab: https://ibb.co/dUgiGy

Comment: Can you try clicking in the menu bar of eclipse Project -> Clean... > tick either your project or all projects -> Clean. This may or may not help, similar issues sometimes occur to me. Either it's fixed this way, or you may have a build path issue.

Comment: I've tried that already and nothing happened :/ Also tried to create a completely new project with junit tests, but it also didn't work.

Comment: Do you see any error when you right click on your project -> Build Path -> Configure build path... ?

Comment: No. Everything seems to be fine.

Comment: What about another version of junit, like junit 4 ? If the problem still occurs, maybe you're missing the junit library in either eclipse or your jre. I can't think of anything else beyond that...

Comment: No matter what version I try to use, the error keeps appearing. I don't think I'm missing the library, but when adding it to the build path, it says "Source location: not found". Might it be the cause?

Comment: That might be it, can you try from another eclipse ?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I've only one computer, so I'm not be able to do so. But I can reinstall eclipse.

Comment: That is what I meant, but you don't need to reinstall, just download the latest version as standalone here https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/ , extract it and you're good to go.

Comment: I've just done it, Didn't help... I've really no idea why.

Comment: I've checked my own eclipse, the "source location" doesn't actually matter. What about trying with another jre ? This is the last thing I can think of :/

Comment: Please add the content of the `.classpath` to your question (which is hidden in the _Package Explorer_, but visible in the _Navigator_ view). Maybe JUnit is set to be visible for test sources only (watch my video for details: https://youtu.be/U-ZTkhek5TU?t=2m32s).

Comment: @howlger It's not set to be visible for test sources only. I've just edited the question and put a link to the content of the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned package/classes are not present in the compile time classpath. Basically, Java has no idea what you're talking about when you say to import this. It can't find them in the classpath.

Download the latest jar from,
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api/5.0.0-M1
Place it in **/WEB-INF/lib** folder of the webapp project and this error should disappear.

Comment: My application is not a webapp project.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is a modular project, **JUnit 5 must be on the modulepath** and the following line must be in **`module-info.java`**:

```
requires org.junit.jupiter.api;
```

If you do not want JUnit in the `module-info.java`, you have to separate the test code as shown in [this short video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U-ZTkhek5TU&feature=youtu.be&t=2m32s).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've found another solution, but that one might work.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, got an answer. In my case, the solution was to change the JRE in Build path to Java SE 1.8. Now everything works fine.