# Eclipse Junit: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, gradle, junit

I have the following problem:

I have a java project that uses gradle. The project structure is:

```
src
- main
-- java
-- resources
- test
-- java
-- resources
```

I have the following test class:

```
package it.main.tests;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.junit.Test;

public class MainTest {

    @Test
    public void mainTests() {
        String s = "ciao";

        assertEquals(s, "ciao");
    }
}
```

If I run the following command: **gradle test** everything is ok. If I try to run the **mainTests** method from eclipse (right click on the method, Run As, JUnit test) I have the following exception:

```
Class not found it.main.tests.MainTest
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: it.main.tests.MainTest
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClass(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClasses(RemoteTestRunner.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
```

This is the **build.gradle** file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

compileJava {
    options.fork = true
}

dependencies {
    // Add all the jar dependencies from the lib folder. 
    compile fileTree(dir: 'src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile fileTree(dir: '//opt/jenkins/wcs_artifacts/WCS_trunk', include: ['beanstyler.jar', 'UnycoIntegrationBean.jar', 'UnycoModels.jar'])
    compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '4.0.1'
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.11'
    testCompile group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-engine', version: "5.2.0"
    testCompile group: 'org.junit.platform', name: 'junit-platform-launcher', version: "1.2.0"
}

task createWCSAdminWar(type: War, dependsOn: [test, classes]) {
    baseName = 'WCSAdmin'
    destinationDir = file("$buildDir/dist")
}

task createUnycoAdminWar(type: War, dependsOn: [test, classes]) {
    baseName = 'UnycoAdmin'
    destinationDir = file("$buildDir/dist")
}

task createDists(dependsOn: [createWCSAdminWar, createUnycoAdminWar])

defaultTasks 'build'
```

And this is the **.classpath** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" exported="true" kind="src" path="/UnycoIntegrationMessages"/>
    <classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" exported="true" kind="src" path="/UnycoModels"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/java"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/test/java"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/resources"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/test/resources"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8/"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.web.container"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.buildship.core.gradleclasspathcontainer">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

Inside **webapp/WEB-INF/lib/** I have the **junit-4.12.jar** file

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: Eclipse Photon (4.8)? Do you have a `module-info.java`? If yes, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51390691/6505250

Comment: Eclipse Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a) without `module-info.java`

Comment: If upgrading to Eclipse Photon does not help, please add the content of `build.gradle` and `.classpath` to your question.

Comment: I have edited the original post

Comment: The imports of your test say JUnit **4**, but your `build.gradle` says JUnit **5**. Does it work if you change your imports to `import static org.juni.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;` and `import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;`?